# Avoid Windows security warning

Tags: windows, batch-file, security-warning

I wrote some very simple bat scripts that just call a ffmpeg command with some parameters.

When I run them from a command line prompt, it just runs without asking anything.

But when I try to call them from another program (maxscript in 3ds max, that allows to runs shell commands with the function ShellLaunch), it displays a security warning asking me if I'm sure I want to execute the program because the numeric signature of the editor has not been checked.

It is really annoying as this message appears behind some other window so to some unalerted user, the program just looks like it blocked.

Is there some way to avoid the display of this warning on our own programs ?

EDIT : If there is a solution for this question I'm still interested but I fixed my problem in my specific case.

For those using 3ds max, here is my solution :
I was using ShellLaunch to run my command, which resulted in the warning displaying. Now I use HiddenDOSCommand, and the warning doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: Please provide your solution as an answer rather than editing the question, so you can mark it as the accepted answer, and the question does not remain open in the SO database...